# How to instruct convert to resize only first TIFF frame if file path specified?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I tested some code which works fine:

```
C:\root\Dropbox\WWW\TIFF\sandbox 17:17:37,86
$c:\cygwin\bin\convert.exe gallery.tif[0] -thumbnail 300x300^ -format jpg gallery.jpg
```

But I want to specify full path to image and it is not works - why it is not working?

It is the same image.

`c:\root\Dropbox\WWW\TIFF\sandbox\gallery.tif[0] == gallery.tif[0]` - why it is not working?

```
C:\root\Dropbox\WWW\TIFF\sandbox 17:17:59,29
$c:\cygwin\bin\convert.exe c:\root\Dropbox\WWW\TIFF\sandbox\gallery.tif[0] -thumbnail 300x300^ -format jpg gallery.jpg
convert: must specify image size `\root\Dropbox\WWW\TIFF\sandbox\gallery.tif' @ error/raw.c/ReadRAWImage/136.
convert: no images defined `gallery.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

Comment: It looks here is some solution but it is not solution really :)
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-09/msg00169.html

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using Cygwin. Cygwin expects a different way to specify paths. IIRC, you should use something like:

```
convert.exe /cygdrive/c/root/Dropbox/WWW/TIFF/sandbox/gallery.tif[0] \
             -thumbnail 300x300^ -format jpg gallery.jpg
```